# Updating a data inserts a new data into the firebase realtime database

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I used the update() function for my code, but it keeps adding a new entry instead of editing the data I want to edit.

```
UpdateData1.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  var updateCrop = document.getElementById('updateCrop').value;
  var updateDescriptionCrop = document.getElementById('updateDescriptionCrop').value;

  if (document.getElementById('updateCrop').value == '' || document.getElementById('updateDescriptionCrop').value == '') {
    alert("Fields should not be empty");
  } else {

    update(ref(database, "Crops/" + updateDescriptionCrop), {
        Crops: updateCrop,
        CropInfo: updateDescriptionCrop
      })
      .then(() => {
        alert("Crop information successfully updated");

      })
      .catch((error) => {
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        // ..
        alert(errorMessage);
      });

  }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that **updateDescriptionCrop** is your key.

In order to update the entity in db you should do this:

```js
update(ref(database), {
  ["/Crops/" + updateDescriptionCrop]: {
    Crops: updateCrop,
    CropInfo: updateDescriptionCrop
  }
}).then(() => {
  alert("Crop information successfully updated");
}).catch((error) => {
  const errorMessage = error.message;
  alert(errorMessage);
});
```

Read more [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#updating_or_deleting_data).

**Update:**

Generate random UUID when you're creating your entries as the key of your entries using [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) library:

```js
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');
function writeData(crops, cropDescription) {
  const entryId = uuidv4();
  set(ref(db, 'Crops/' + entryId), {
    Id: entryId,
    Crops: crops,
    CropInfo: cropDescription
  });
}
```

And then when you want to update your entry, use this id:

```js
update(ref(database), {
  ["/Crops/" + cropId]: {
    Id: cropId,
    Crops: updateCrop,
    CropInfo: updateDescriptionCrop
  }
}).then(() => {
  alert("Crop information successfully updated");
}).catch((error) => {
  const errorMessage = error.message;
  alert(errorMessage);
});
```

Comment: It works on the first entry I added. If I add a 2nd entry on to the database, and I edited the 1st entry. It adds another entry.

Comment: Could you also add the format of the entries and their fields in database ?

Comment: Format of the entries and fields in the database? I have only two textboxes. Crop and CropDescription. I don't have any unique id when I am adding a new entry with me add function. Do you think an unique key/id will help me with this error?

My database in firebase only consist of
Crops (Table name), CropInfo and CropInformation.

Comment: Yes that would definitely help and also is a best practice. Generate a random UUID as the id of each entry using this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid

Comment: Alright, I'll try to create a unique ID, and that will be my key when updating something.

Comment: That's right. I also updated my answer. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you so much Amirhossein. I finally got it working. Many thanks to you.

Comment: You're welcome. Please pick my answer as the correct answer if it helped you. Thanks.